# iOS Second Display

Tags: ios, airplay, uiscreen

I do not get the Second Display to Show any other then Mirroring my Device Screen.
I allways see only the mirrored device screen on my tv.
This is My Code i hope someone can help me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(configureScreens) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];

[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(configureScreens) name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];

[self configureScreens];

return YES;
}

-(void)configureScreens
{
NSUInteger screenCount = [[UIScreen screens] count];

NSLog(@"%u",screenCount);

if (screenCount == 1) {
    //single windows
}else if(screenCount == 2) {
    UIScreen *appleTvScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIWindow *tvWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:appleTvScreen.bounds];
    tvWindow.screen = appleTvScreen;
    tvWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    tvWindow.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tv"];

    tvWindow.hidden = NO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you try the sample source code TVOut on GITHub - https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/TVOut.

It uses similar code to yours but packaged in a class which you can copy over and call from your own code.

It should solve your display problem.

Comment: How would you detect the device name. If there are multiple airplay device, how to select which TV to select?